# Save the path only, not adding a file name or format

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I would like to save the path that the file should be saved at but I do not want the user to add the name of the file and its format. Just select the map where the file should be saved.

The code below doesn't work to save the path because you also need to adda file name.

```
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        lblDestination.Content = saveFileDialog.FileName;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: @C4ud3x That's literally the opposite of what they asked for ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use the FolderBrowserDialog instead, this allows you to pick just the folder.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want the `FolderBrowserDialog` instead of the `SaveFileDialog` you're currently using.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the current dialog you have, then `Path.GetDirectoryName()` will allow you to strip out the file name from `saveFileDialog.FileName`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)